# Google People API user.gender.read not returning values

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I am getting responses for the personFields - birthday, email, name, etc. but no response for gender.

My gender is private, but user.gender.read scope prompts the user for their consent to share their gender info. Still it is not giving a response for "genders".

CALL:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me
H- Authorization Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Parameters: key <api_key>
personFields: addresses,ageRanges,biographies,birthdays,calendarUrls,clientData,coverPhotos,emailAddresses,events,externalIds,genders,imClients,interests,locales,locations,memberships,metadata,miscKeywords,names,nicknames,occupations,organizations,phoneNumbers,photos,relations,sipAddresses,skills,urls,userDefined
```

Response:

```json
{
  "resourceName": "people/*numbers*",
  "etag": "*etag*",
  "metadata": {
    "sources": [
      {
        "type": "PROFILE",
        "id": "*numbers*",
        "etag": "*etag*",
        "profileMetadata": {
          "objectType": "PERSON",
          "userTypes": [
            "GOOGLE_USER"
          ]
        },
        "updateTime": "2023-08-09T19:29:22.635711Z"
      }
    ],
    "objectType": "PERSON"
  },
  "locales": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "ACCOUNT",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        }
      },
      "value": "en"
    }
  ],
  "names": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        },
        "sourcePrimary": true
      },
      "displayName": "*name*",
      "familyName": "*name*",
      "givenName": "*name*",
      "displayNameLastFirst": "*name*",
      "unstructuredName": "*name*"
    }
  ],
  "coverPhotos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        }
      },
      "url": "*url*",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        }
      },
      "url": "*url*"
    }
  ],
  "birthdays": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "ACCOUNT",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        }
      },
      "date": {
        "year": *yyyy*,
        "month": *m*,
        "day": *d*
      }
    }
  ],
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "verified": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "ACCOUNT",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        },
        "sourcePrimary": true
      },
      "value": "*email*"
    }
  ],
  "ageRanges": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "*numbers*"
        }
      },
      "ageRange": "TWENTY_ONE_OR_OLDER"
    }
  ]
}
```

basically i am not getting a response for any private info other than birthday which is weird

please help me out, i am a no-code user

I have add the scopes and granted permission on oauth consent screen. I have tried to call it with and without my API key, it's not working.

I have all people api scopes added to my console and gave consent for it through the oauth2 screen.

Comment: if the info is private your not going to get it.

Comment: the basic userprofile scope includes gender, but if it is private user.gender.read is recommended and user is prompted to consent to share that info with the app, so technically that should allow the app to view gender even if it is private because the user is consenting to share it. but even after that it is not generating a response.

Comment: **so technically that should allow the app to view gender**  You know I said that to Google team probably around 2015, its still not working.  Try setting it public and see if it works.   I wonder if i can find someone in my contacts to take up the discussion with again.